# How can I determine which NSArray has caused the Exception in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a small project with about 5 or 6 arrays.  Im getting a problem saying that my NSArray collection was mutated while being enumerated.  But it doesn't tell me which Array its referring to.

How can I visualize which one it is in order to fix it?

Comment: Do you have a breakpoint set in the debugger for All Exceptions? Go to the Breakpoints Navigator, click +, choose "Exception Breakpoint" and then press Done. Run it again and it should break close to where the mutation is occurring. Also this kind of thing often happens when you've got multiple threads running (which makes debugging nice and hard.) Have a look at the Threading Programming Guide and read up on the @synchronized() keyword too.

Comment: Thanks Tim...dunno how to mark your answer as the correct one but indeed I needed to add Exception Breakpoints and sure enough it told me the culprit

Answer (score 0):

You can always use your friend NSLog, as you are looping through your arrays:

```
NSLog(@"your_array_name contains: %@", your_array_name");
```

It never hurts to print out the contents of each of your arrays to make sure you know what's being stored in them.